# How to retrieve from session object in JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags

I have a User Object which contains details like Name, Contact Details etc & I am storing this object in a session attribute. How do I save the name and contact details in a String variable in JSP Scriplet?

I tried using

```
String uname1 = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute(${requestScope['users'].getName()});
```

and many other combinations
But it fails

My JAVA code

```
user = userDetails.getByUsername(username);

request.getSession().setAttribute("uname", user);
```

and in JSP I have

```
<%

String uname = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute("uname");
if (uname != null) {
response.sendRedirect("home.jsp");
}

%>
```

How Do I extract "name" from "uname" object and store it into a variable to be used for checking null value ?

Comment: user is a User Object right ?

Comment: Yes nassim, 

Users user =  new User();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could store only the name in the session instead of the User object

```
user = userDetails.getByUsername(username);

request.getSession().setAttribute("uname", user.getName());
```

because i see that in the jsp you are expecting a String object, if you want to store a User object than you should expect a User object instead of a string in the jsp

```
user = userDetails.getByUsername(username);

request.getSession().setAttribute("uname", user);

<%

User user = (User) request.getSession().getAttribute("uname");
if (user.getName() != null) {
response.sendRedirect("home.jsp");
}

%>
```

Comment: But I need the entire object because I need to also set different parameters for different conditions. I don't want to set 35 POJO in session attribute to use it separately.

Comment: doesn't the second solution help ? user is User object in the jsp

Comment: I tried that.
`Users obj = request.getSession().getAttribute("uname");`

Error - Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to Users

Comment: yes look at my exemple ! you should cast it to (User)

Comment: Yes it worked, Thank you so much.
But since the piece of code was on login page itself, the user object was coming as null and it was not going on login page even for the first time. So I wrapped it up in a condition to check if session is new or not. Please look into this and tell me if I missed a scenario.
`if(!session.isNew()){
 Users user = (Users) request.getSession().getAttribute("uname1");
 if (user.getName() != null) {
 response.sendRedirect("home.jsp");
 }
}`